# Converting an ajax object into a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an ajaxed in element that I'm trying to convert into a string that can be stored into a variable. After I put it into the variable, the variable does not `console.log`; it says it's an object. How do I get it to print out the content of the variable?

Here's the code I'm using:

```
$.get('/Default.aspx?PageID=15018909&A=WebApp&CCID=21437&Page=1&Items=500', function(data){
    $('#ajaxResults').html(data).find("ul").remove(); 
    var ajaxResult = $('#ajaxResults').html($('#myArray').text());
    console.log(ajaxResult);
});
```

I also need to run a replace() on that ajax result, but I can't because the object isn't a string.

Comment: What do you think you are setting that variable to? As it stands, you are assigning the HTML of `#ajaxResults` and assigning the result of that operation to the variable.

Comment: so how do i turn that into a string? I've tried String(ajaxResult) but nothing. I'm not that well versed in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You are taking the `data` back from `$.get()` and sending it to an element, then reading the element in. `data` already contains the information you need, see [$.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

Why wouldn't you just retrieve the unparsed text data from the `jqXHR` parameter to the success callback?

```
$.get('/Default.aspx?PageID=15018909&A=WebApp&CCID=21437&Page=1&Items=500', function(data,status,jqXHR){
    console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
});
```

Or conversely, just look at the data itself?

```
$.get('/Default.aspx?PageID=15018909&A=WebApp&CCID=21437&Page=1&Items=500', function(data,status,jqXHR){
    console.log(data);
});
```

If you know the data is already an object

```
JSON.stringify(data)
```

Comment: because the data isn't an object. It's HTML that contains head tags, scripts and unordered lists. That's what this is about: $('#ajaxResults').html(data).find("ul").remove(); var ajaxResult = $('#ajaxResults').html($('#myArray').text()); Stripping away the html and other stuff so i can stay with the remainder string.

Comment: Oh crap. It isn't just text you are stuffing in, it is complete HTML? So the question is how to strip off the html to get the core data? Now I understand why.

Comment: Can you post here or in a gist a sample of the html?

Comment: Wow, messy stuff, but I guess it is what your server served up, right?

Comment: From the looks of it: You have html tag, then head-to-end-head, then body, immediately followed by the interesting data sort of structured like an array, then a ul and some closing stuff. Is that right?

Comment: The interesting data itself looks like JSON, but with some br tags inside some of the fields.

Comment: Oh, it is messier than that. The ul node is *inside* the enclosing array.

Comment: What is #myArray? I don't see that on the page anywhere?

Comment: sorry, that wraps the [[ and the <ul>

Comment: OK, so why not just `$('#ajaxResults').html(data).find("ul").remove();` (as you did) followed by `txt = $('#myArray').text(); console.log(txt);`?

Comment: You could always convert it to a JS object, and then do some fun processing in it...

Comment: i get an error saying it's an object. I had to go a different route because of this. Thanks all

Comment: Well @Damien, glad it worked out... but what did you do in the end?

Comment: I ended up doing some server-side stuff and parsing on the server end. The server spit my array out exactly how i wanted it and then i passed it to javascript. BTW, this is a server that has nothing to do with the site so i just served up the page on the server and iframed the content into the original site. Cheating, i know, but i had to get it done. Thanks for your help!